# IBatis executing multiple sql statements in one method go with Oracle DB , is that possible?

Tags: java, ibatis

### IBatis executing multiple sql statements in one method go with Oracle DB , is that possible?

I am trying to create a

`<delete id="onDeleteCleanUpDocumentMetadatas">
        DELETE FROM DOCUMENT_METADATA dm WHERE id #documentId#;
        DELETE FROM DOCUMENT_METADATA2 dm2 WHERE id #documentId2#
</delete>`

method that will clean up metadata tables related to file in case that file got deleted. On Delete Cascade is not an option for me and that's why I am doing it manually.